# Why does shape=record not draw the arrow?

Tags: graphviz

Note that I set the rank to `same`.

The code is:

```
digraph R {

  rankdir = LR
  node [shape=record];

  {rank = same; rA sA}

  rA -> sA;
}
```

The output is:
[image]

Comment: It works for me in GVEdit 2.38, arrow is drawn with your exact code.

Comment: Which version of graphviz are you using (dot -v)

Comment: dot - graphviz version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304)

Answer (score 2):

When I run this on a Mac with the same version I see the following error:

```
 Warning: flat edge between adjacent nodes one of which has a record shape - replace records with HTML-like labels
   Edge sA -> rA
 Error: lost rA sA edge
```

I'm not sure why you don't see this error message.  But based on the date of the [code commit](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/commit/763f02ef3cb7fbb62336f372b42279bd63266727), it was added after 2.38.0 and is part of 2.40.1.  The code change adds a return which is why you don't see an arrow.

[image]

Comment: Line 1088 here is a bit strange (twice the same condition), probably one of the conditions should be shapeOf(hn) (has been corrected in the master version; won't solve the problem at hand).

Comment: Question is also should the return be present and the messsage be seen as warning or what would otherwise be the way to write it.

Comment: We could always raise this as an issue via https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/issues.

Comment: Yes please do it.